# SQL: Complete my select with an other select in the same request

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to add a new data in an old select, but the data that i want is something like a row count of an other table

I tried to use a double select with a count in the first (see the request below), it may be not the best usage. i really don't know. if someone got an idea ! :p

So i want to add to my old request a column like "count likes" where we see how many likes an item get (see the db image below).

Thanks guys for reading and helping me :)

My old request :

```
SELECT image_item.link, image_item.alt, item.id, item.name, item.short_description, item.publish_date FROM item, image_item WHERE item.image = image_item.id ORDER BY publish_date desc limit 3
```

My actual request :

```
SELECT image_item.link, image_item.alt, item.id, item.name, item.short_description, item.publish_date, count(like_system.item)
FROM item, image_item, like_system
WHERE like_system.item = item.id AND item.image = image_item.id
AND like_system.item = (
SELECT item from like_system, item WHERE like_system.item = item.id AND item = item.id
)
```

my db model :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHVQu.jpg

I got this error :

```
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'urbexblog.image_item.link'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: `from like_system, item WHERE like_system.item = item.id` This way to join tables was deprecated about 25 years ago. Consider using **proper** [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Don't post your DB model as image, we can't copy/paste to rebuild the structure with datas. Post it as **text**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Cid Yeah sure, i will do it ! i'm learning that's  why it's not perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use group by clause when you aggregate some data:

```
SELECT 
image_item.link,
image_item.alt, 
item.id, 
item.name, 
item.short_description, 
item.publish_date, 
SUM(NVL2(like_system.item,1,0)) as likes_count
FROM item 
 INNER JOIN image_item
    ON item.image = image_item.id
 LEFT JOIN like_system
    ON like_system.item = item.id
GROUP BY
image_item.link,
image_item.alt, 
item.id, 
item.name, 
item.short_description, 
item.publish_date
```

Comment: Something not perfect, actually your request take only items that have 1 and more likes but i need all off these, 0 likes too

Comment: @Steven Douillet check the answer now